# display background color over an element for a specific time then disappears __ javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, background, overlay, layer

is there a way where I can (as title) then return it back as normal

I tried to store outer element of an element and modify style for example to .style.backgroudColor="red";

but when I change it back as what I stored in variable it distroys the style of the element

NOTE:I want it dynamic so that it can display  over any element whether it is p div img or whatever tag you think of ...

After Edit:
I see like there is misunderstanding of my problem

treat it as it is type of light where it close and open close and open ... that's what I want ... 3 seconds it will show the original tag and then it show red color background for 3 seconds then return to original tag

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a document.querySelectorAll();

I found this guide from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

With this method you can select all tag as you want.

Comment: it's completely different what I asked in question and what you answered

Comment: what I want is that ... for example I have p tag and then I want to display over it a color and then disappears... If you see there is type of light where it close and open close and open ... that's what I want ... 3 seconds it will show the original tag and then it show red color background then disappears

Comment: for example I have an img show infront of me which is covered by a layer of color for example red then after 3 seconds the layer of red colour will disappear and the image will show

Comment: another example is for example ... A text which shows hello Jack ... when I load the page and the text of <p> tag shows which contains hello Jack wait for 2 seconds then layer of yellow color cover over it (At that time I don't see what's behind the layer ). After 3 seconds the yellow layer will disappear and I can see the text

Comment: please read the question another time I made edit ... thank you.